# I don't understand this code for rows in media (css)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, row, media

Hi I don't understand this code  for cards

my container for cards is this before heigh of container is 100% and width is auto

```
  .container-cards {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 600px);
        
        gap: 1em;
        
    }
```

but when I tried to type media code it deosnt work for all cards the hegiht isnt the same like from the start. If I write instead for rows  this `grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 600px)` the height will be fixed. I don't understand why this code doesn't work for rows set to auto.

```
   @media (max-width: 767px) {
        /* Small screens: 1 card in a row */ 
        .container-cards {
            
            grid-template-rows: auto;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
          }
      }
```

Comment: Can you create a runnable snippet which shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example At the moment you have two different classes demonstrated. I assume that isn’t so in your actual code?

Comment: basically when i create container that has cards with height of 600px  for each card like in the code. When I use  `grid-template-rows: auto` the height of last 3 cards isnt the same even with rows to be set to auto in media. I don't know why is that. I could instead add this ` grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 600px); but that will make me 5 rows for each card and the height is fixed, but I think this is wrong way. Already tried everything  auto_fill doesn't work either

Comment: Did you try `grid-template-rows: repeat(5, auto);`?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are referencing to wrong class

```
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    /* Small screens: 1 card in a row */ 
    .container-cards {
        
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      }
  }
```

You need to target same class in media rule for it to change size and position of content on different screen sizes

Comment: oh sorry I did rewrite it to english the class is alright

Comment: but th eproblem is still the same for seting it to auto